# Dúvidas com relação à uma string grande estourando a tag td da table

Tags: html, css

Estou  recuperando alguns dados do bando de dados MySQL e ele esta trazendo tudo certinho. Porém, um dos campos e uma URL que quando e passada para uma tag `<td>` da table ele passa direito é não respeita a largura máxima de 40px, vejam no exemplo abaixo. Ela passa direto e continua na coluna do token (obs: o token esta vazio).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber se tem como mostrar a string toda sem alterar o tamanho do campo e sem dar um orverflow hidden no CSS.

Comment: Amanda poderia postar seu HTML e CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Amanda, adicione o atribute de CSS

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

neste campo em específico, olha um exemplo de como ele funciona abaixo:

```css
div {
width:50px;
border:1px solid red;
}
a {
overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="https://www.ecowebdesign.com.br">https://www.ecowebdesign.com.br</a>
</div>
```

Se quiser a documentação oficial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Boa sorte

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade `word-break: break-all;`. Irá quebrar textos longos que possam ultrapassar a largura do elemento onde está, veja:

```css
td{
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td style="max-width: 100px;">
         https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397944/duvidas-com-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-h%c3%a1-uma-string-grande-estourando-a-tag-td-da-table
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Veja como fica **sem** a propriedade:

```css
td{
   /*word-break: break-all;*/
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td style="max-width: 100px;">
         https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397944/duvidas-com-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-h%c3%a1-uma-string-grande-estourando-a-tag-td-da-table
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: De nada Amanda. Veja como agradecer no [tour] ;)